# Googlesheet extract specific text from cell, based on range

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I've got a problem, I'm not sure can be done with formulas.

I can do it with some script writing, but would prefer the sheet be "Live" and use formulas.

I have a list of products, and within the name of the product is the type of product it is (T-shirt, Sweatshirt etc)

But it's not always in the same place, I have a list of Types, and what I want to do is create a formula that will populate pull the type from the name if it finds it in my List

(hope that makes sense)
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DXmEbzJS02oMlGYrKI6XsUPuyCI9XqoRo2_4GZXIZN4/edit?usp=sharing

This is a sample of the data, I've got Product Titles in Column A, The Expected output in column B, and the list of types in column F.

I've tried using a combination of find and mid commands, but can't figure out how to get it to compare with every type in my list.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming A2:A contains product names, F2:F contains a list of product types, and we want C2:C to contain product types extracted from product names in A2:A, then it can be achieved with the following formula in cell C2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,JOIN("|",
QUERY({F$2:F,ARRAYFORMULA(LEN(F$2:F))},
"select Col1 where Col1 is not null order by Col2 desc")))))
```

### Explanation

`REGEXEXTRACT`, extracts a substring that matches a regular expression. `x|y` matches *x* or *y*, preferring *x*. We construct a regular expression containing all product types from the list (F2:F), delimited by `|` using `JOIN`.
The list of product types is first sorted descending by string length, so that `REGEXMATCH` will try to match the longest types first. It doesn't matter in the particular example sheet you provided, but would be necessary if you had a type that is a substring of another type, e.g. *Shirt* and *Polo Shirt*.